# New screen doesn't receive touchdown event

Tags: android, input, libgdx, screen

I have a screen that is opened from a main menu. the screen is shown correctly but the event touchdown doesn't work, If I use only a Game class it work but in a new screen the code isn't executed....Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am really newbie in libgdx....this is the code....

```
public class GameScreen implements  ApplicationListener, InputProcessor,Screen {

    private BitmapFont font;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    private Stage stage;
    private Sound mp3Sound;

    public GameScreen() {
        super();
        System.out.println("costruttore");
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        render();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("touchDown");   
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("touchup");
        return false;
    }


    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkcollision(Rectangle attore1, Rectangle attore2) {

        System.out.println("checkcollisions........");
        mp3Sound.play();
        return flagcollision;
    }


    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) {            
            Gdx.app.exit();                 }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        System.out.println("render gioco");
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();


        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.getBatch().begin();
        stage.getBatch().draw(img, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        stage.getBatch().end();
        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can't just call render whenever you like, you have to let the UI thread handle that. Second off, I presume this is the "second" screen you talk about? You can't have multiple screens be the applicationListener.

Basically what i would do is something like (pseudo code):

```
public class GameClass implements Game/ApplicationListener
public class ScreenOne implements Screen, InputProcessor
public class ScreenTwo implements Screen, InputProcessor
```

Have the GameClass setScreen(screenOne) in onCreate()
have ScreenOne call setScreen(screenTwo) in an OnClick/touchUp function
put Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); in show() of BOTH screens

Comment: Thanks, it work. the Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); was the winner code line :) also I deleted render() by the constructor and put the application listener in the main class. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your touch down method return value

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
         System.out.println("touchDown");   

    return true;
}
```